# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_bz2' al instalar "Pandas"

Tags: python, linux, pandas

Después de instalar "*pandas*" en un servidor (***Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS***) obtengo el error de que ***no encuentra el módulo "_bz2"***. Dentro de éste servidor tengo diferentes versiones Python instaladas y funcionando.

**Python2.7** y **Python3.6** en:

> /usr/bin/

**Python3.9** está en la ruta:

> /usr/local/bin/

A la hora de instalar "pandas" usé:

```
python3.9 -m pip install pandas --user
```

Para que "*pandas*" pueda funcionar instalo los módulos necesarios:

`sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev` , `sudo apt-get install liblzma-dev`

Después de ver que la instalación ha sido exitosa puedo comprobar en **python2.7** que "pandas" si, pero "_bz2" no:

```
python
Python 2.7.17 (default, Mar  8 2023, 18:40:28)
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> print(pd.__file__)
/home/xxxx/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.pyc
>>>>>> import _bz2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named _bz2
```

En **python3.6** al revés, no se instaló "pandas" pero si "_bz2":

```
python3.6
Python 3.6.9 (default, Jan 26 2021, 15:33:00)
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
>>> import _bz2
>>> print(_bz2.__file__)
/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_bz2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
>>>
```

y por último, en **python3.9**, donde más necesito que esté instalado todo sólo está "pandas":

```
python3
Python 3.9.2 (default, Jul  1 2021, 17:40:21)
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/xxxxx/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pandas.compat import is_numpy_dev as _is_numpy_dev  # pyright: ignore # noqa:F401
  File "/home/xxxxx/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    import pandas.compat.compressors
  File "/home/xxxxx/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/compat/compressors.py", line 7, in <module>
    import bz2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/bz2.py", line 18, in <module>
    from _bz2 import BZ2Compressor, BZ2Decompressor
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_bz2'
>>>
```

Después de probar algunas alternativas no consigo la manera de instalar el módulo _bz2 en la ruta de Python3.9 (la app que está corriendo en el servidor tira de esta versión)

**He visto la posibilidad de copiar el fichero de la 3.6 a la 3.9 con:**

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_bz2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /usr/local/lib/python3.9/
```

**O también de enlazar directamente con:**

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_bz2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /usr/local/lib/python3.9/
```

No sé si es la manera más correcta de hacer funcionar pandas donde yo quiero, pero después de intentarlo varias veces no lo consigo, y quisiera evitar tener que instalar o actualizar nada de python.

**¿Alguien con el mismo problema y haya conseguido una solución?**

Y algo que no entiendo nada es cómo es posible ver esto:
**sudo find / -name '*_bz2*'**

```
/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_bz2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/_bz2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/test/test_bz2.py
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/test/__pycache__/test_bz2.cpython-39.pyc
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/test/__pycache__/test_bz2.cpython-39.opt-1.pyc
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/test/__pycache__/test_bz2.cpython-39.opt-2.pyc
```